# Artifactory REST API

Tags: ansible, artifactory, devops

i am new to DevOps.

I am writing a playbook in Ansible to update the Artifactory on my CentOs 7. In my script, i am looking to write some method to get the version of running Artifactory on my machine.

Do anyone have idea to get this?

I think it could be done through Artifacotry Rest API but not sure how to do this if it is possible with Rest API.

Feel free to write me back if any further details required from me.

Comment: Don't know if anyone get chance to check this. i just think a way to get this from artifactory.properties.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to get the current version manually? If you just want to ensure it is updated to the latest, I can't see why that would be required.

Comment: A Email notification will be informed user about the current version and updated version through YML, this is the reason for getting current version.

Answer (score 3):

The Artifactory [Version and Add-on information](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-VersionandAdd-onsinformation) REST API method returns the Artifactory version:

```
GET /api/system/version

{
  "version" : "4.15.0",
  "revision" : "40350",
  "addons" : [ "build", "docker", "vagrant", "replication", "filestore", "plugins", "gems", "composer", "npm", "bower", "git-lfs", "nuget", "debian", "opkg", "yum", "cocoapods", "conan", "vcs", "pypi", "rest", "license", "blackduck", "ldap", "sso", "layouts", "properties", "search", "filtered-resources", "p2", "watch", "webstart", "support", "xray" ],
  "license" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell, you can get the output by using the below commandlet.

You can replace with your URI.

(Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "http://192.168.1.10:8081/artifactory/api/system/version").version